# PHP MYSQL -> UPDATE column with variable if that variable isn't null or empty

Tags: php, mysql

Sorry, but i'm new to PHP, so i will look like a noob.

As the title says, i made this method which updates user data:

```
function update($userid, $name){
Try{

    $stmt=$this->db->prepare("UPDATE users
                          SET 
                          name=:name,
                          WHERE userid=:userid");
    $stmt->execute(array(':name'=>$name));

   } Catch(PDOException $e){
     echo $e->getMessage();
  }
  }
```

That code is working right, but i want to know if it's possible, the "name" column just update if the variable coming from:

```
$user->update($userid, $name);
```

From $name, is not null or not empty. If it's null or Empty, the  MYSQL UPDATE function should not be done.

Comment: `name` != `nome` btw and you have a trailing comma.

Comment: *"That code is working right"* - I *highly* doubt that. Not with what you posted.

Comment: i just translated to english to make you guys understand what is written, i forgot to translate nome to name. But it's working

Comment: well, translations can cause problems. I know what "nome" means, but code is code.

Comment: btw; I noticed the edit, you still have a trailing comma, which is why your code is breaking right now.

Comment: here: WHERE userid=:name"); ? That why i was trying "COALESCE" and i left the comma on the final ,but iwithout that it's working the code

Comment: `WHERE userid=$userid` well... that leaves you open to an sql injection, so use a prepared statement "all the way".

Comment: In addition to @Fred-ii- you must use binding for userId too. You should not echo the pdo exception message as it will provide information about your database which I'm pretty sure you don't want to happen in production

Comment: Hi, yes Matei, you're right, what should i use instead?

Comment: @sygamers did you see Oliver's answer? did it solve the question? if so, consider accepting it. If it did not solve it, you will need to place a comment under it about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead.

```php
function update($userid, $name) {
    try {
           if (!empty($name) and !empty($userid)) {
           $stmt = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE users
                                    SET 
                                    name=:name
                                    WHERE userid=:userid");
           $stmt->execute(array(':name' => $name, ':userid' => $userid));
           }
    }
    Catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

#### Explanation

1. Removal of the *trailing comma*.
   As stated by @Fred -ii- you had a trailing comma in your SQL query after the SET (i.e `SET name=:name,`).
   The comma in SQL queries are used to separate multiple updates from one another so `UPDATE table SET col1 = "val1", col2 = "val2"` and so on. Since you are only updating one column, you don't need the comma
2. The `empty` method checks whether the variable `$name` has been set and is not false. See [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php).
3. Removed the SQL-Injection-Vulnerable in :userid=$userid

#### Why i think it is better to have an if-statement inside the function

1. A function should be reusable and it costs nothing to call a function
2. In clean code you should avoid using if-statements, which means, you should not always have surround an if-statment before calling a function which could be called in other parts of the code, too. What happens when you add another parameter?
3. I know this is discussable.

Comment: *"Use this"* - the question is: "why"? as in "why should they use what you posted.

Comment: "If it's null or Empty, the MYSQL UPDATE function should not be done."  is what he want to archive... Where do you read a Why?

Comment: I'm talking about what was wrong with their code and why it broke. If I decide to delete my comment up there, your answer won't hold much water; as the expression goes ;-)

Comment: Is the explanation enought for you? @Fred-ii-

Comment: sure, however they should be testing if it's empty before passing it in the function. That stands to fail.

Comment: But now you are satisfied :-)

Comment: it's much better. FYI: I don't think the OP knows what to do with answers/solutions given. Whenever I nudge people to accept answers, my comment gets flagged about it; *sigh*. What can we do, eh?

Comment: @Fred-ii- No need to nudge people :-) It is better to have a complete answer for others who read this. Instead of having an incomplete answer, but accepted.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys! But can i ask why it's bad act testing if it's empty before passing it into the function? @Fred-ii-

Comment: @sygamers Well, in my opinion I think it is better to have it inside a function. See my answer...